# How can I increase baud rate for bluetooth in Arduino?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, embedded

I am doing a project in Arduino and want sensor data on my Android. For this purpose I am using HC-05 BT module and Bluetooth Terminal app on Android. But Bluetooth Terminal is receiving data at constant rate (1 sec, I think). And I want to receive data in 10 millisecs. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int RX=0;
int TX=1;

SoftwareSerial Bluetooth(RX,TX);
int i=0;

void setup() {
    Bluetooth.begin(9600);
    Bluetooth.println("The controller has successfuly connected to the phone");
}

void loop() {
    Bluetooth.write(i);
    i++;
    delay(5);  
}
```

Comment: can you provide Arduino code? I suppose it is sending data at constatnt rate of 1 sec.

Comment: ok, I will provide code.

Comment: Your issue is something *other* than the baud rate.

Comment: @ChrisStratton , can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: From your code we see that you sending data each 5ms. And you say that Andorid receives it at rate 1sample/second? Also i suppose that it is not full code, and the issue lies in other part of firmware.

Comment: 9600 baud is capable of moving your message in less than 1/100th of a second, so it is not fault in the magnitude of delay you are seeing, though you might need to change it for your ultimate goal.    As an aside, you might want to reconsider using the Arduino hardware serial pins for software serial.  But your actual problem could well be on the Android side.  **Show your Android code and the data you are receiving** - does it count consistently, or are there missing numbers or garbled messages?  Try writing received data to the Android log and using logcat with timestamps.

Comment: You can try to send data through Arduino serial 0 port and check if it arrives in time. This will show if your problem lies in Arduino field.

Comment: @VladimirTsykunov , it is full code. Maybe my issue is with android app. I am using an app named "Bluetooth Terminal" for receiving data.

Comment: @ChrisStratton , on android data is received continuously, no number is missing, the only problem is data is being received after 1 sec almost. As I said , there may be problem in the Bluetooth App I am using. So, is there any other method of doing the same?

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://blog.oscarliang.net/multiwii-bluetooth-change-baud-rate/):

> The bluetooth module baud rates are set by an hexadecimal index from
>   ‘1’ to ‘C’. Indexes are: 1:1200, 2:2400, 3:4800, 4:9600, 5:19200,
>   6:38400, 7:57600, 8:115200, 9:230400, A:460800, B:921600, C:1382400
>
> To set a default baud rate, enter this command
>
> AT+BAUD
>
> For example for multiwii, we need 115200 as the BT baud rate, we would
>   enter AT+BAUD8.
>
> If successful you should be returned “OK” in the serial monitor.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the baud rate of the HC-05 by using AT commands.

Use:

```
    AT+UART=57600,1,0
```

here is a [tutorial](http://dronehitech.com/change-baud-rate-bluetooth-module/)

Comment: The baud rate of the link between the Arduino and the GSM module does not explain the observed issue.

Comment: Even if he uses 9600, data should arrive at 1 byte per 1 ms. But the author claims that he received in 1 second

Answer (score 1):

If it is the full code then you sending not printed characters. And also after you will get i=127 you will send characters from upper part of ascii table. And think what will happens when i>255. Try this code in loop:

`Bluetooth.println("this is test code")`

instead of writing `Bluetooth.write(i);`

You can get more info about [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)  and more about [Serial.print](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print) and [Serial.write](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Write)

Comment: Also change delay(5) to delay(5000), otherwise you will receive 200 records per second.

Comment: The goal was to receive 100 records per second, ie, delay(10) if there was nothing else causing a slowdown.

Comment: I have experience in receiving more than 200 uint16 samples per second in Android without any problem, but the data was sent in back thread. From you description we know that you use terminal, and i don't see any reason to have such a rate in gui window. Anyway you have to change your arduino code. Because terminal is for printable characters only.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the baud rate of the HC-06 by using AT commands

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial btSerial(2, 3); // RX, TX
/*
* Connect pin 2 Arduino to pin TX HC-06 
* Connect pin 3 Arduino to pin RX HC-06
*/ 
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Enter AT commands:");
btSerial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
if (btSerial.available())
Serial.write(btSerial.read());
if (Serial.available())
btSerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

AT

AT+BAUD4==>9600

AT+BAUD8==>115200